# How to delete line(s) below current line in vim?

Tags: vim

Is there a command to delete a line (or several lines) that is immediately below current line?
Currently I'm doing it as:
<kbd>j</kbd><kbd>dd</kbd> and then <kbd>.</kbd> to repeat as needed.
Is there a command that would combine all these?

UPDATE: The reason I would like to have such command is that I don't like to move away from current position, yet be able to delete lines below.

Comment: I think @Peter Rincker's answer should be marked as the answer

Comment: done @gixxer, thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 192, accepted):

The delete ex command will work nicely.

```
:+,$d
```

This will delete all the lines from current +1 till the end ($)

To delete the next 2 lines the follow range would work, `+1,+2` or shorthand `+,+2`

```
:+,+2d
```

As @ib mentioned the `:delete` or `:d` command will move the cursor to the start of the line next to the deleted text. (Even with `nostartofline` set). To overcome this we can issue the ``` `` ``` normal mode command. ``` `` ``` will jump back to the exact position before the last jump, in this case the `:d` command. Our command is now

<kbd>:</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>,</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd><kbd>`</kbd><kbd>`</kbd>

Or as one ex command

```
:+,+2d|norm! ``
```

To make this easier we wrap this all up in a command:

```
command! -count=1 -register D :+,+<count>d <reg><bar>norm! ``
```

Now to delete the next following 3 lines:

```
:3D
```

This command can also take a `{reg}` like `:delete` and `:yank` do. So deleting the next 4 lines into register `a` would be:

```
:4D a
```

For more information

```
:h :d
:h :command
:h :command-register
:h :command-count
:h ``
```

Comment: Note that this is a fairly easy solution that works "out of the box" and is generalizable to other commands (for example, `:+1,+5s!a!b!g` will replace a's with b's on the 4 lines after the cursor). See :help command-ranges for some more examples.

Comment: This straightforward solution would be great, if only it does not move the cursor.  At least, the command should look like `:+,$d|norm!\`\``.  By the way, as stated in the question, author of the question would like to delete several lines below the current one, not necessarily all way down to the end of file.

Comment: @ib: Would the answer be improved by a more detailed explanation of ranges? Maybe `set sol`? How to use the `\`` mark?

Comment: @Peter:  Probably, it would be.  By the way, turning `sol` off alone does not solve the issue: when one deletes, say, three lines using `:+,+3d`, the cursor is moved to the line next the deleted ones.

Comment: @ib: I have incorporated your suggestions into the my answer. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: `:.,$d` takes the current line also (instead of starting with the next line)

Answer (score 132):

<kbd>d</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> should work.

This means delete all rows until end of file from current cursor.

Comment: THIS is the best one!

Comment: simple & the best

Comment: This worked. Very simple and efficient solution. Same way the `dg` also works opposite direction.

Answer (score 34):

This will delete ALL lines below the current one:

```
jdG
```

Unfortunately that will move the cursor to the beginning of current line after the deletion is made.

Comment: And will delete every line till the end of the buffer, too.

Comment: I misread the original question, sorry. Thought the OP wants to delete ALL lines below the current one. Changed my post.

Answer (score 8):

well, to do it simply you could use the xxdd command. Most of the time I know (at least have an idea) the size of the script I am editing. So, the command as below is usually more than enough :

- 99dd
- 999dd   to remove 999lines starting at the cursor position.
- 9999dd
- 99999dd for very long script ;)

Answer (score 4):

The other solutions are informative, but I feel it'd be simpler to use a macro for this:

`qq` (begins recording)

`jddk` (go down, delete the line, and go back up - i.e. the thing you want to do)

`q` (end recording)

Now you can do `@q` to perform this action, maintaining the cursor at the current position. You could also do something like `5@q` to delete 5 lines below the cursor.

And finally, if you're repeating the action more than once, you could just type `@@` after the first time you run `@q` (this repeats the last used macro - in this case `q`)

Answer (score 2):

This is a job for marks!

Try `` maj20dd`a ``

`ma` sets the file-specific mark 'a', `j20dd` does the deletion you want (20 lines in this case), and `` `a `` restores you to the mark's position (line and column).

Obviously this pattern can be extended to do anything you want before returning to the mark. If you use `mA` (or any other capital letter) the mark will actually be unique across files, so you can even edit elsewhere before returning. If you have a very frequent usage you could make it a macro as suggested above.

Answer (score 1):

You could enter the number of lines to delete:  <kbd>j</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> <kbd>k</kbd>.

Comment: Final `k` moves the cursor above the initial line.  Also, cursor column position will be lost because of `dd`.

Comment: @ib: Not in my tests it doesn't.  Have you actually tried it?  Note the initial **j**.

Comment: I'm sorry, my first point was wrong (when I've tried the command out, I have not noticed that the count I specified ('20', in your example) was greater than the number of lines till the end of the buffer).  But the second one remains: column position of the cursor changes after `dd` (to the first non-blank character of the line next to the deleted lines, I believe).

Comment: @ib: Yes, I agree the column position changes.

Comment: Please make an insignificant edit of your answer, so I can upvote it.  I think your answer does not deserve a negative rank after all.

Comment: These commands indeed return cursor to the original line, but not to the original position. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>

Answer (score -2):

Just for the fun of it, you can define a little function that does
exactly what you described: deletes the next `n` lines below the
current line and restores the initial cursor position.

```
function! DeleteNextLines(n, reg)
    let l = line('.')
    let m = min([a:n, line('$')-l])
    if m > 0
        let c = col('.')
        exe '+,+'.m 'd' a:reg
        call cursor(l, c)
    endif
endfunction
```

Also, you can define a command that accepts the number of lines
to delete (one, if omitted) and the register name to use as an
optional argument (just like the `:delete` command).

```
:command! -range=1 -register -bar D call DeleteNextLines(<count>, <q-reg>)
```

Additionally, you can define a mapping for triggering the above
`:D` command, if it is necessary.

Comment: for example, to map to comma,d (press ',' followed by d) insert the following lines (after entering the above answer by @ib. )
1: `let mapleader = ","`
2: `nmap <leader>d :D<CR>`